# Monitor OutOfMemory in ECS Fargate

Tags: java, out-of-memory, amazon-ecs, apm

our java microservice(3 tasks of each 8gb cpu,32gb memory) is running in ECS fargate and we observed `OutOfMemory` in logs,however when i check the memory metrics
max is showing only 14gb memory peak out of 32gb.. overall peak never reached more than 35% but still getting out of memory errors.No clue why none of metrics showing at container level of 100% memory usage at time of out of memory.Tried various APM tools and none of those not showing that
Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to see the _actual_ error message, but this is most likely due to the JVM memory settings. Java won't use 100% of the available RAM by default. You have to tune the JVM memory settings to take advantage of all the available RAM.

Comment: I get it thanks @MarkB but my observation around why none of aws metrics/graph shows out of memory ... so far logs only showing ``` java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ```  if i checks ECS tasks memory utilization never shows more than 35%.. definately the container crashed when OOM happened

Comment: The container didn't "crash". The primary process in the container, your java process, crashed and exited. Once the primary process exits, the container stops.